# readTextFile function returns undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, txt

```
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function readTextFile(file)
{
    let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                let allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}


readTextFile("/input.txt");
```

I want to read a txt file and print it to console but I'm getting undefined. What is the reason for that?

Comment: This is node code? If yes, use `fs.readFileSync`

Comment: `const fs = require('fs');
let text = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt');`     I'm still getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
let text = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt');
text = text.toString();

console.log(text);
```

Use toString() method returns the buffer object.